# Polynomial quotient rings over the integers and UFDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $p > 1$. Is $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^p -1)(y^p - 1)$ a UFD? Does this depend on the value of $p$?

It is about 10 years since I learnt about fields and rings - from memory I would say no, but I am struggling to recall why or find any theorems that would immediately tell me one way or the other.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$ is a UFD - is there some result that can tell you when a quotient of a UFD is also a UFD?

Comment: Doesn't the D in UFD stands for "domain"? This doesn't look like an integral domain...

Comment: $x-1$ and $y-1$ are zero-divisors

Comment: Sorry, I intended for $p > 1$.

Comment: Yes, of course that for $\;p>1\;$ , since $\;x^p-1=(x-1)(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1)\;$ ....and $\;x-1\;$ still is a zero divisor.